# Displaying button on table from database

Tags: java, swing, button

Alright so I am working on a project where I have made an application in java that should represent a loan system which connects to a user database and product database. I have a homepage where the user can select a category and when that button is pressed it displays what is inside that category in the database. Then I want to add a button out from each item that it displays but no matter what I do it will not show. Hope you can help.

I am still pretty new to Java, my first project in this language.

```
public class ProductTable {

    //Building table for display of products on storage
    public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        // names of columns
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        // add button column
        columnNames.add("Loan");

        // data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                row.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
            }

            // add button to row
            JButton button = new JButton("Register");



            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // handle button click
                }
            });
            row.add(button);

            data.add(row);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }
}
```

This is the image of how it looks when it am running it:
[image]

I am pretty stuck because I have tried many things. But no matter if I add a panel to the homepage or my table model it will not display.

Comment: Seems like you are using Swing. You can tag your question with Swing tag in order to attract corresponding attention. Please also provide a [mre].

Comment: do some research, apply what you learned, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected. That said: __do not__ add components as data, instead implement a custom renderer/editor showing a button (and go through the usual steps to make it clickable, you'll find examples when doing research :)

Comment: Check out [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for one approach.

Comment: Using `JButtons` in a `JTable` is not a user-friendly design.  It's too easy to left-click the wrong button when the `JButtons` are that close to each other.  A better design is to allow the user to select a `JTable` row by left-clicking on the row and left-clicking on the one `JButton` below the `JTable`.